# Copy Range value and format

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy Cells `B2:B26` from `sheet1` to `sheet2` `B8:B32` with the **value and format** if a change occurs in `sheet 1`. The problem is it seems to run in loop for about 10 seconds. I can't see what's wrong. This is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Copy_Range
End Sub
```

```
Sub Copy_Range()

Sheets("liste d'élèves").Range("B2:B26").Copy

With Sheets("Feuil1").Range("B8:B32").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Which sheet has the `SelectionChange` handler?

Comment: Does it run in a loop and then crash?

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable events. Also, I highly recommend limiting the scope of your `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. Do you really want any change to trigger the macro? Maybe you are looking in a change within a specific region. If so, specify that region and run the macro when the selection change overlaps (`Intersects`) with the specified region.

```
Sub Copy_Range()

Application.EnableEvents = False <--- Off

Sheets("liste d'élèves").Range("B2:B26").Copy

With Sheets("Feuil1").Range("B8:B32").End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True <--- On

End Sub
```

Comment: The range I am importing is a list of students and it  will change often. It dosen't crash after the loop. I also have to make changes to the list on the sheet "liste d'élèves" for certain students. I guess it would good if it ran on a worksheet change instead of a selection change but when I try that it doesn't run at all.